# Validate Error while refering res.partner module - openerp 7

Tags: python, openerp-7

Hi I am trying set relation between my module with `res.partner` module. I have set  one column in my module which link with `partner_id` of `res.partner`, at time of adding this field in view I am getting this error. `Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture` Please check below code which I have return for my module.

```
    class visa_application(osv.Model):

           _name = "visa.application"

           _columns = {
                   'x_surname' : fields.char('Surname', size=128, help="Enter Surname", required=True),
                   'x_maiden_name' : fields.char('Maiden Name', size=128, help="Enter Maiden Name"),
                   'x_fore_name' : fields.char('Fore Name', size=128, required=False, help="Enter Fore Name"),
                   'customer_id' : fields.many2one('res.partner', 'partner_id') }
```

*** View.xml

```
    <record id="visa_application_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">visa.application.form</field>
        <field name="model">visa.application</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="VisaApplication" version="7.0">
                    <group col="2">
                        <field name="x_surname" />
                        <field name="x_maiden_name" />
                        <field name="x_fore_name" />
                        <field name="customer_id"  widget="selection" eval="ref('res.partner.name')"/>
              </group>
                </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Error Log

```
    2014-05-06 07:30:10,365 1644 ERROR vrs openerp.netsvc: ValidateError
    Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131102-002522\Server\server\.\openerp\netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131102-002522\Server\server\.\openerp\service\web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131102-002522\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131102-002522\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 144, in wrapper
```

Please guide me

Comment: Can you set the log level to debug in openerp-server.conf and append the error messages to your question?

Comment: hi miq, I have already putted error log from openerp-server.conf in my question. Please let me know if you are looking for some thing more. Thanks for you help.

Comment: So the log level is "debug" and there were no log lines starting with timestamp and "DEBUG"? I'm asking because usually when I get these errors, there's some kind of hint in the debug level that indicates where the problem could be. Does the view work if you temporarily remove the widget and eval parameters from the customer_id field?

Comment: Yes, If I remove customer_id filed it works well.

Comment: Yes, I understood from the original question that the view works without the customer_id field. But if you leave the customer_id field intact and remove the _parameters_ called 'widget' and 'eval', will the view work?